# Argument replacement using ?1 with @Query annotation

Tags: java, sql, spring, annotations

I am using @org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query annotation for an sql query as follows;

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select ITEM_ID from db.ITEMS "
    + "where dbms_lob.instr(ITEM_HISTORY, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('<PERSON><NAME>?1</NAME></PERSON>'), 1, 1) > 0")
List<String> findByName(String name);
```

This query searches for `<PERSON><NAME>?1</NAME></PERSON>` inside the blob called ITEM_HISTORY and returns id's of matching ITEMs.

?1 should be replaced by String name automatically, but it is not working. I am almost sure it is because of the quotation marks(') around `'<PERSON><NAME>?1</NAME></PERSON>'`. However I couldn't figure out how to do it. **What is the correct syntax here?**

Comment: %?1 instead of ?1 does not work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed `'<PERSON><NAME>?1</NAME></PERSON>'` to `'<VERMITTLER><VTNR>' || ?1 || '</VTNR></VERMITTLER>'` and it is working.

Please note that `||` is the concatenation operator for Oracle. Thus this solution would only work on Oracle. The idea is simple though, ?1 should not be inside quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `?1` with `{0}`

Comment: I couldn't find any usage of {0} to get the first argument.                     @Query("select u from User u where u.emailAddress = ?1") This is the standard usage